# Getting Permission denied when doing Git Pull

Tags: git, git-pull, git-fetch

I am getting the following error when doing git pull:

```
$ git pull
remote: Azure Repos
remote: Found 281 objects to send. (30 ms)
Receiving objects: 100% (281/281), 49.09 KiB | 12.27 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (143/143), completed with 32 local objects.
error: unable to write file .git/objects/pack/pack-343f861beecc48677d06622d75c7a47437cbcf2f.pack: Permission denied
fatal: unable to rename temporary '*.pack' file to '.git/objects/pack/pack-343f861beecc48677d06622d75c7a47437cbcf2f.pack'
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
```

I validated is not a permissions issue as I clone the repo to another folder and can do Pull Push and everything.

googling the issue seems to be related maybe to the size... before this I did a Git Pull --all I believe is related to that.

Any help will be really apprecited. Thanks

Comment: It *is* a permissions issue: your OS is denying your Git command permission to create a new file in `.git/objects/pack/`. Why *that* is will depend on your OS and many additional details.

Comment: I have the same problem - will clone into another directory but not the one I want. I even tried mv-ing it to where I want it, same problem. My destination folder is a folder mounted using SSH-Fuse and I think the problem is long file names. I can scp the files back to the server and it worked. Anything special about your destination?